# Key Error while trying to fetch data from API

Tags: python, keyerror, intune

I have used below mentioned code to fetch data from Intune warehouse, but faced an error as attached:

[image: Key Error]

```
#pip install requests pandas plotly
import requests
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Replace with your actual Intune OData API endpoint
intune_api_url = "API_Link"

# Fetch data from the Intune API
def fetch_data():
    response = requests.get(intune_api_url)
    data = response.json()
    return data['d']['results']

def create_dashboard():
    # Fetch data from Intune OData API
    intune_data = fetch_data()

    # Convert data to pandas DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame(intune_data)

    # Filter compliant device
    compliant_devices = df[df['ComplianceState'] == 'Compliant']

    # Get the number of compliant devices
    num_compliant_devices = len(compliant_devices)

    # Create a simple dashboard with plotly
    fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Indicator(
        mode="number+delta",
        value=num_compliant_devices,
        title="Compliant Devices",
        delta={'reference': 0}
    )])

    fig.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_dashboard()
```

I tried checking response status using below code:

```
import requests
import json
response_API = requests.get("API")
print(response_API.status_code)
```

the output for above is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

401 indicates that you have not authenticated; therefore, you are unauthorized to access this data.